# Changing flights at Chennai (MAA) Airport

Tags: air-travel, transit, air-india, maa

I would be flying from Mumbai (BOM) to Port Blair (IXZ) in the month of February next year by Air India. This is the first time I would be traveling with connecting flights, earlier I have flown with direct flights. This is my itinerary.

Air India   AI-570   06:15   BOM   08:10   MAA

Plane change at Chennai | Waiting: 2h 20m

Air India   AI-551   10:30   MAA   12:40   IXZ

Is the waiting duration of 2 hours and 20 minutes sufficient? In case I won't be able to catch my connecting flight from MAA, due to delay in arriving flight, will Air India take care of arrangements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

2:20 should be plenty.  If the first flight is delayed, causing you to miss the connection, *and both flights are on the same ticket*, then yes, Air India will take care of you.  If you bought the two flights separately, then you're on your own.

Comment: yes I was looking for BOM-IXZ, and found this flight.

Comment: @onkar -- then you have nothing to worry about.  And have fun, the Andamans might be the most beautiful place on Earth.

Comment: @onkar -- and pack your own lunch for the flight.  Air India is a terrible airline in many ways, most noticeably the food.